# Use Argonaut in Play framework with Reads and Writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework, argonaut

I know how to do json parsing using play json library for play application. For example I have following code:

```
class PersonController extends Controller {
    case class Person(age: Int, name: String)
    implicit val personReads = Json.reads[Person]
    implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]

    def create = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
        rs.body.validate[Person] match {
            case s: JsSuccess => ...
            case e: JsError => ...
        }
    }
}
```

How should I write the code like Reads and Writes using Argonaut instead of Play json?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://argonaut.io/doc/parsing/) for argonaut are fairly comprehensive in this regard. You need to generate a `Codec` with

```
implicit def PersonCodecJson: CodecJson[Person] =
    casecodec2(Person.apply, Person.unapply)("age", "name")
```

And then use `decodeValidation` to get a `Validation` object back.

```
val result2: Validation[String, Person] =
    Parse.decodeValidation[Person](json)
```

Comment: You didn't get my question. I want to write some code to confirm to Play's Writeable and Readable type. I am not asking about validate actually.

Comment: Could you give some background on what and more importantly *why* you are trying to do what you are?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for?

```
class PersonController extends Controller {

  case class Person(age: Int, name: String)

  implicit val PersonCodecJson: CodecJson[Person] =
    casecodec2(Person.apply, Person.unapply)("age", "name")

  val argonautParser = new BodyParser[Person] {
    override def apply(v1: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, Person]] =
  }

  def argonautParser[T]()(implicit decodeJson: DecodeJson[T]) = parse.text map { body =>
    Parse.decodeOption[T](body)
  }

  def create = Action(argonautParser) { implicit request =>
    Ok(request.body.name) //request.body is the decoded value of type Person
  }

}
```

Actually, you need a body parser that parses the request body using argonaut instead of play json. Hope this helps.