# WebSocket Missing implicit Message Flow Transformer for custom data type in play 2.6

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, playframework-2.6

I am trying to establish a web socket connection between client and server, but an implicit MessageFlowTransformer is required for data types, the play documentation only introduces String and JsValue transformation, and I have the following data types :

```
sealed trait InEvent
sealed trait outEvent

  final case class AckInEevent(serial: Long) extends InEvent
  final case class AckOutEevent(serial: Long) extends outEvent
```

```
//theWebSocket action handler :

def accept = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[InEvent, outEvent] { request => .....}
```

I got an error indication

```
could not find implicit value for parameter transformer: play.api.mvc.WebSocket.MessageFlowTransformer[InEvent, outEvent]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sealed trait InEvent
sealed trait outEvent

final case class AckInEevent(serial: Long) extends InEvent
final case class AckOutEevent(serial: Long) extends outEvent

import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val ackInEeventFormat = Json.format[AckInEevent]
implicit val ackOutEeventFormat = Json.format[AckOutEevent]
implicit val inEeventFormat = Json.format[InEvent]
implicit val outEeventFormat = Json.format[outEvent]

implicit val messageFlowTransformer =
  MessageFlowTransformer.jsonMessageFlowTransformer[InEvent, outEvent]

def accept = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[InEvent, outEvent] { request => ???}
```

`libraryDependencies += "org.julienrf" %% "play-json-derived-codecs" % "6.0.0"`

https://github.com/coding-jam/lagioconda/blob/master/frontend/app/protocol/Protocol.scala

Comment: thanks, what if I use  Argonaut encode and decode, the the Json.Format would not work

Comment: @med10 With Play framework you're supposed to use play-json, not Circe,  Argonaut, Jackson, µPickle or anything else. Otherwise you'll have to implement conversion between type classes of different libraries yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833584/use-argonaut-in-play-framework-with-reads-and-writes/